# What does "Drive Friendly -- The Texas Way" mean?

Tags: driving, texas

[image]

Saw this sign as I entered Texas earlier this week, as well as digital display boards reminding drivers to also "Drive Friendly - The Texas Way".

[image]

What exactly is the Texas Way? Do Texans have some sort of special customary way of driving? I tried briefly looking up the term through Google and it seems even Texans are conflicted about what the intent of the saying is -- some say it's related to pulling over to the slow lane if a faster car wants to pass you, which is something I'd attribute less to being Texan specifically and a more universal United States thing (or perhaps Californian thing, which I'm commonly used to already just as a good way of showing courtesy).  Some say there it's about Texans honking their horns at out-of-state plates but that seems like such an odd thing to push Texans to do.

Hopefully someone can clear up what this means -- especially to someone like me who's from out-of-state. I'll be passing through Dallas/Ft. Worth soon so it'd be nice to get a headsup if there is some meaning behind this.

Comment: Having watched many films set in Texas, and having seen it on the news, I suppose it means saying "Have a nice day y'all" before you shoot out of the car window.

Comment: Pulling over to the slow lane to let faster drivers pass isn't only a US thing either. In many european countries you can (and will) be fined if you drive in the fast lane when not overtaking other cars (with obvious exemptions like traffic jam.

Comment: You shouldn't take slogans like this literally. Does "Virginia is For Lovers" imply that lovers don't belong in other states?

Comment: You are parsing the phrase incorrectly. "The Texas Way" does not modify "Drive Friendly", i.e. it is not a specific way of driving friendly. It is more of the reverse, driving friendly is one of the characteristics of being a Texan. It is consistent with the Texas way of conducting yourself, going about your business, etc.

Comment: For folks that aren't aware, the name "Texas" derives from a Caddo word for "friend", so mottos/slogans of "Friendship state" and "Drive Friendly" have a pun element.

Comment: If you've ever driven anywhere near Los Angeles, coming into or leaving the city, you'd know that EVERYONE wants to drive on the left lane, going slow or not. I think it's ego driven because the sign says "slower traffic keep right" but "slow" means "bad" and "I'm not bad, I'm good" so no one ever pulls to the right, almost never. Super frustrating. Lots of passing on the right side is what I've experienced in my 20 years here. Idaho, Utah and other states are much different.

Comment: It's at least better than messing with 'em

Comment: @coblr Near my city there was a two lane road to which a "slow traffic" lane was added in a slope, in its right side; many times the slow lane was empty while the two regular lanes were clogged. A few years ago they eased the curve and repainted the lines so it looked like there was no "slow traffic" lane but a new lane on the left side, and suddenly people started using the rightmost lane.

Comment: @Barmar Of course not, it means that anyone who is not a lover had better get out of Virginia!

Answer (score 59, accepted):

I don't really have a source for this, but don't overthink it. "Friendship" is the official [state motto](https://www.tshaonline.org/handbook/entries/state-motto). Which doesn't really mean anything—state mottos aren't some guiding ethos everyone in the state has to live by—but they tend to get trotted out for signage and campaigns.

They're signs [asking that you drive in a friendly fashion](https://www.drivingnorthtexas.com/txdot-urges-drivers-to-drive-friendly-drive-safe/)—watch for pedestrians and cyclists, be careful of your speed, use caution in construction zones, and so on. I'd imagine that this also includes things like avoiding aggressive driving and helping to let others change lanes or merge on/off the freeway.

As with all promotional slogans or etiquette campaigns, I wouldn't read too much into it, and Texans (I am not one) surely have opinions about their fellow drivers that may be less than friendly. The Texas Department of Transportation is just appealing to drivers to be more friendly (better) drivers.

Comment: Kind of cracks me up because in Texas they drive fast and cars are king (drivers are in general not friendly to pedestrians and cyclists in my experience). It's just a lip service motto that sounds nice.

Comment: One can only assume that if driving friendly was truly the Texas way, they wouldn't find it necessary to put up signs asking people to do it.

Comment: @ZachLipton But the signs are at the state line for people entering from the non-friendly states outside Texas!

Comment: But Florida might be justified in calling itself The Sunshine State.

Comment: @sq33G Although, putting it on sign *does* make it a self-fulfilling motto.

Comment: Calling friendly driving "the Texas way" is also an attempt to encourage good driving by appealing to state pride, whether its truly the way of Texans or not

Comment: @badjohn "The Sunshine State" is Florida's nickname, not it's motto.

Comment: @KennethK.I missed that distinction.

Comment: I remember they floated the idea a couple decades ago of taking this campaign even further to change the motto on the license plate to "The Friendly State" or "The Friendship State" or something similar, and everyone lost their mind at the thought of changing from "The Lone Star State" to one of those. Didn't happen, of course.

Comment: @badjohn FWIW there are several other states that have on average more sunshine than FL

Comment: @jdf: Cars are definitely not king.  Trucks are.

Comment: re Florida being "The Sunshine State" ... actually [it's 10th](https://worldpopulationreview.com/state-rankings/sunniest-states), which if you think about it, is really low for that being its motto...

Comment: Apparently AZ tops that list.  No surprise there.  The Phoenix metro is called "the Valley of the Sun", which it lives up to pretty well.

Comment: @PeterM So, they should use "A Sunshine State"?

Comment: I've lived in Montreal (Canada), Rhode Island (though I worked in Massachusetts) and Texas.  Texas (and, for that matter, much of *the South*) tends to be very friendly: "After you, sir", "Thank you, ma'am".  My daughter went back to school in Montreal and used to  comment about how much more polite folks were here in Texas.  For what it's worth, the equivalents might be "Drive without paying attention, The Rhode Island Way" and "Drive in the most aggressive fashion, the Massachusetts Way" (and drive like you may survive winter, the Montreal way).

Comment: @Flydog57 That would indeed be a fitting motto for [Montreal](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rtF_UiwPRYo)!

Answer (score 24):

What may be happening is this.  Let me know if this isn't it.  You may possibly be thinking the sign means:

> Drive friendly.  Do so by driving ***specifically*** the Texas way, not another state's way.

However, what it means is this:

> Drive friendly.  Driving friendly ***is*** the Texas way.

It just means don't drive crazy in general.  Don't go twice as fast as the speed limit.  Don't harass people.  Don't drive drunk.  Don't do bad stuff in general.

As far as the driving rules go, Texas is usually pretty normal.  Their driving rules are about the same you see in any other state.  There might be a few states with really weird rules that matter for normal, everyday driving, but Texas isn't one of them.

If you drove from California through Arizona and New Mexico to Texas, then just drive the same way you do in Arizona and New Mexico.  For normal, everyday, passenger car driving, the rules are basically the same between AZ, NM, and TX.  (I think CA is similar as well, but I'm not completely sure.  I've lived in AZ and TX though, and they are very similar.)

---

By the way, for English in general, the *grammar and such* they use in those signs can have either of those two meanings mentioned above, but the *cultural context* says it's the second one in this case.  I'm guessing it's the same in the UK, Canada, and Australia, but there may be one or more English-speaking countries where the culture is different in this matter.

Something this reminded me of just now: This isn't really a cultural context issue, but a word definition issue.  In New Zealand, you might see this type of road sign:

[image]

Many Americans won't understand what that sign means.  In our form of English, "zip" is basically just a verb, and a lot of times, schools don't teach this specific dialectual difference.  Some Americans may figure it out immediately, but many of us would probably at least have to think about it for several seconds (particularly if we can't see the road very much further ahead, because of hills and stuff blocking our view).

However, if we translate that into AmE, it basically becomes:

[image]

For New Zealand, "zip" is easily both a noun and a verb, but for the US, it's mainly a verb.  The sign is talking about two roads merging into one, and it's saying to have cars from both roads take turns, one car at a time.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118224/discussion-on-answer-by-panzercrisis-what-does-drive-friendly-the-texas-way). You can go on with the conversation in that chatroom, here further comments will be deleted. And for now the comments here are locked